# PHP SimpleXML failure after slight change

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a script that takes form data and submits it to an XML file, but after adding a few extra nodes the script is returning a blank page and fails to write to XML, not even returning the echo 'add another' at the end. I'm totally at a loss on this one. After consulting our server provider everything looks fine on their end. Any suggestions?

Heres the original code:

```
include ('resources/header.php');    
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('../products/pending/products_pending.xml');

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('product')->item(0);

$name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);
$price = $element->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0);
$our_price = $element->getElementsByTagName('ourprice')->item(0);
$quantity = $element->getElementsByTagName('quantity')->item(0);
$size = $element->getElementsByTagName('size')->item(0);
$color = $element->getElementsByTagName('color')->item(0);
$vendor = $element->getElementsByTagName('vendor')->item(0);
$category = $element->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0);
$subcategory = $element->getElementsByTagName('subcategory')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('product');

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('inventory_type', 'inventory_type'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('model_number', 'model_number'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('sku', $product_sku));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('category', $_POST['product_category']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('subcategory', $_POST['product_subcategory']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', $_POST['product_description']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('manufacturer', 'manufacturer'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('barcode_upc', 'barcode_upc'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('color', $_POST['product_color']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('size', $_POST['product_size']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('min', 'min'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('max', 'max'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('quantity', $_POST['product_quantity']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('avg_cost', 'avg_cost'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('freight', 'freight'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('w_cost', '$'.$update_our_price));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('retail', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('our_price', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('min_price', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_number', $update_vendor));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_item_number', $vendor_item_no));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', $_POST['product_name']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('price', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('ourprice', '$'.$update_our_price));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('vendor', $update_vendor));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('consignmentfee', $consignment_fee));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('websiteprice', '$'.$update_website_price));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('image', $image));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('status', 'Pending'));

$xml->getElementsByTagName('pending_products')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);

$xml->save('../products/pending/products_pending.xml');

echo '<div class="container content">';
echo '<a href="add_product.php">Add Another</a>';
include ('resources/footer.php');
```

Here's the new code:

```
include ('resources/header.php');

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('../products/pending/products_pending.xml');

$element = $xml->getElementsByTagName('product')->item(0);

$name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0);
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0);
$price = $element->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0);
$our_price = $element->getElementsByTagName('ourprice')->item(0);
$quantity = $element->getElementsByTagName('quantity')->item(0);
$size = $element->getElementsByTagName('size')->item(0);
$color = $element->getElementsByTagName('color')->item(0);
$vendor = $element->getElementsByTagName('vendor')->item(0);
$category = $element->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0);
$subcategory = $element->getElementsByTagName('subcategory')->item(0);

$newItem = $xml->createElement('product');

$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('inventory_type', 'a'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('model_number', $vendor_item_no));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('sku', $product_sku));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('category', '24'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('subcategory', $_POST['product_category']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('description', $_POST['product_description']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('manufacturer', 'manufacturer'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('barcode_upc', $product_sku));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('color', $_POST['product_color']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('size', $_POST['product_size']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('lease', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('book_depr', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('tax_depr', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('min', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('max', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('quantity', $_POST['product_quantity']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('avg_cost', 'avg_cost'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('freight', 'freight'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('w_cost', '$'.$update_our_price));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('retail', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('our_price', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('min_price', '$'.$_POST['product_price']));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('price_a', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('price_b', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('price_c', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('spiff', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_number', $update_vendor));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_item_number', $vendor_item_no));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_last_cost', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('p_vendor_last_date', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s1_vendor_number', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s1_vendor_item_number', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s1_vendor_last_cost', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s1_vendor_last_date', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s2_vendor_number', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s2_vendor_item_number', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s2_vendor_last_cost', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('s2_vendor_last_date', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('notes', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('pos_reminder', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('invoice_notes', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('image', $image));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('selection_code', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('warranty', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('locator', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('bar_label', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('date_in_house', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('unit', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('weight', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('loyalty_exempt', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('food_stamp', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('healthcare', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('scale', 'test'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('status', 'Pending'));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('name', $name));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('vendor', $vendor));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('consignmentfee', $consignmentfee));
$newItem->appendChild($xml->createElement('websiteprice', $websiteprice));

$xml->getElementsByTagName('pending_products')->item(0)->appendChild($newItem);

$xml->save('../products/pending/products_pending.xml');

echo '<div class="container content">';
echo '<a href="add_product.php">Add Another</a>';
include ('resources/footer.php');
```

Comment: There is a detailed description of what’s wrong in your apache’s `error.log` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$element->getElementsByTagName()` returns a DomNode object, but `$xml->createElement()` asks for two strings.

So when you try to create an element with `$name` or `$vendor` as a value, you're asking PHP to cast a DomNode to a string, but it's not able to do that. You may find some errors like this in your log file :
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string on line XX`

In order to get a string, you need to use the nodeValue property :

```
$name = $element->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$description = $element->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$price = $element->getElementsByTagName('price')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$our_price = $element->getElementsByTagName('ourprice')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$quantity = $element->getElementsByTagName('quantity')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$size = $element->getElementsByTagName('size')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$color = $element->getElementsByTagName('color')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$vendor = $element->getElementsByTagName('vendor')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$category = $element->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$subcategory = $element->getElementsByTagName('subcategory')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```